# How two check if a certain button was just clicked while other conditions are being met in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have three buttons and a stop button. The first button is enabled and the other two are disabled. With each click of the stop button the next button becomes enabled and the other two disabled. Also with each stop button click a new alert comes up depending on with button is enabled.

I have tried something similar to

```
//html
<div class="Input" id="Input">
  <div class="onOff">
    <button id="on" class="on" onclick="activate();  gillespie();">Begin Simulation</button>
    <button id="off" class="off" onclick="disableA(); stopDesc()  ifClicked()">Stop Simulation</button>
  </div>

  <div class="mRNAbutton">
    <button id="rnaLow"    class="mRNAlow"  onclick="fmRNAlow()" >Low mRNA]</button>
    <button id="rnaMedium" class="mRNAmed"  onclick="fmRNAmed()" >[Medium mRNA]</button>
    <button id="rnaHigh"   class="mRNAhigh" onclick="fmRNAhigh()">[High mRNA]</button>
  </div>

  <div class="pButton">
    <button id="proMed" class="proteinMed" onclick="fproteinMed()">[Protein = 8,000]</button>
  </div>


//javascript
function ifClicked()
  {
  var stopButton = document.getElementById('off');
  var butn1      = document.getElementById('rnaLow');
  var butn2      = document.getElementById('rnaMedium');
  var butn3      = document.getElementById('rnaHigh');

  if(stopButton.clicked && butn1.enabled)
    {
    alert("hi");
    }
  else if(stopButton.clicked && butn2.enabled)
    {
    alert("hello");
    }
  else 
    {
    alert("Yo");
    }
  }
```

I expect that whichever button is currently enabled, has a different alert because thats the one that's enabled.

Comment: You'll need a semicolon after `stopDesc()` - your `ifClicked()` won't trigger otherwise. Also, `stopButton.clicked` is redundant as the method is only called when clicking on that button.

Comment: After adding the semi colon and taking away the stopButton.clicked, nothing is happening and none of my alerts are popping up.

Comment: what is the delay for the button clicked? if there is a click on another button in between time is it playing? your question is very fuzzy

Comment: Each button is used to run a dynamic line graph so each button is essentially a different input that changes the graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a var to memorize when the button is clicked
**HTML**

```
<div class="Input" id="Input">
  <div class="onOff">
    <button id="on"  class="on"  >Begin Simulation</button>
    <button id="off" class="off" >Stop Simulation</button>
  </div>

  <div class="mRNAbutton">
    <button id="rnaLow"    class="mRNAlow"  >Low mRNA]</button>
    <button id="rnaMedium" class="mRNAmed"  >[Medium mRNA]</button>
    <button id="rnaHigh"   class="mRNAhigh" >[High mRNA]</button>
  </div>

  <div class="pButton">
    <button id="proMed" class="proteinMed" >[Protein = 8,000]</button>
  </div>
```

**JS**

```
const bt_On        = document.getElementById('on')
    , bt_Off       = document.getElementById('off')
    , bt_rnaLow    = document.getElementById('rnaLow')
    , bt_rnaMedium = document.getElementById('rnaMedium')
    , bt_rnaHigh   = document.getElementById('rnaHigh')
    , bt_proMed    = document.getElementById('proMed')
    ;
var stopButton_clicked = false

bt_On.onclick = function()
  {
  activate();
  gillespie();
  }
bt_Off.onclick = function()
  {
  disableA();
  stopDesc();
  ifClicked();
  stopButton_clicked = true
  }

bt_rnaLow.onclick    = fmRNAlow;
bt_rnaMedium.onclick = fmRNAmed;
bt_rnaHigh.onclick   = fmRNAhigh;
bt_proMed.onclick    = fproteinMed;


function fmRNAlow()
  {
  //... 
  }
function fmRNAmed()
  {
  //... 
  }
function fmRNAhigh()
  {
  //... 
  }
function fproteinMed()
  { 
  //... 
  }
function  activate()
  { 
  //... 
  }
function  gillespie()
  { 
  //... 
  }
function disableA()
  { 
  //... 
  }
function stopDesc()
  { 
  //... 
  }
function ifClicked()
  { 
  if(stopButton_clicked && bt_rnaLow.enabled)
    {
    alert("hi");
    }
  else if(stopButton_clicked && bt_rnaMedium.enabled)
    {
    alert("hello");
    }
  else 
    {
    alert("Yo");
    }
  }
```